# How to get line numbers of the code that i have selected in code editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When i am selecting some code in the editor part in eclipse i want to fetch the starting line no of that code and the end line no of that code.
It would be a great help if someone can help me.

Comment: Get it where? Is this part of an editor you are writing or something else?

Comment: If you want to copy the line number where the cursor is to the clipboard, hit Ctrl+L, Ctrl+C and Esc or Enter. Otherwise, please describe what you want to do with an example.

Comment: @greg-449, suppose i have my editor and in that a program is opened and i have selected some part of code so in my editor i have done some contributions to the eclipse environment that when i will select some code and i will right click on it i have my own option added in that list now what i want is when i click on that option it should display the lines no of code that i have selected, only starting line no and end line no.

Comment: @howlger suppose i have my editor and in that a program is opened and i have selected some part of code so in my editor i have done some contributions to the eclipse environment that when i will select some code and i will right click on it i have my own option added in that list now what i want is when i click on that option it should display the lines no of code that i have selected, only starting line no and end line no.